# Save machine state from within guest machine with VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is there a way to save machine state from the guest machine with Windows XP using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to by closing the window the VM is in and then choosing `Save Machine State` from the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's note clear to me if the WinXP you mentioned is the host or the guest or both, or if you want to do this interactively or in the background.

If the host machine is a Win box, you could do a remote desktop session to the host and interactively work with the VirtualBox controls.

If the host machine is a Linux box, you could possibly use VNC or ssh to get back into the host to play with the VirtualBox controls.